# Deleting elements with specific substring in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list with many elements that I have extracted from an html page using Beautiful Soup.
Within this list I have many elements with the same substring, and I would like to extract every element that contains that substring.

My list looks like:

```
[
u'File:Saddam Hussein (107).jpg',
u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)',
u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)',
u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)',
u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)',
u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)',
u'File:AlBakr.jpg',
... (and so on) ...
]
```

And I would like to delete and element that has the string "(page does not exist)".

Any thoughts on how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> lis = [u'File:Saddam Hussein (107).jpg', u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)', u'File:AlBakr.jpg', u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)', u'File:Chiracsaddam.jpg', u'File:Donald saddam.jpg', u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)', u'File:SaddamandCuellar.jpg.jpg', u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)', u'File:SaddamBaghdadwalkabout.jpg', u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)', u'Kurdish Patriotic Front (page does not exist)', u'File:TrialSaddam.jpg', u'Mohammad Rashdan (page does not exist)', u'Emmanuel Ludot (page does not exist)', u'Marc Henzelin (page does not exist)', u'Adnan Khairallah Tuffah (page does not exist)', u'Nidal al-Hamdani (page does not exist)', u'Ali Hussein (page does not exist)', u'File:SaddamandRana.jpg.jpg', u'Saddam Kamel Majid (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fn (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fnb (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fnb (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fnb (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fnb (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fnb (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fnb (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fnb (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fnb (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fnb (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fnb (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fnb (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fnb (page does not exist)', u'Template:Fnb (page does not exist)']
```

If you want to modify the original list:

```
>>> lis[:] = [item for item in lis if "(page does not exist)" not in item]
```

Or to create a new list:

```
new_lis = [item for item in lis if "(page does not exist)" not in item]
```

Comment: Why the copy, `[:]`? I'm pretty sure that's unnecessary.

Comment: @johnthexiii `lis[:]` is not a copy, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297774/what-is-the-difference-between-a-b-and-a-b

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, perhaps a better question is why keep the original reference? I am not implying that it is a bad thing, I'm just curios.

Comment: @johnthexiii OP mentioned *"would like to delete"*, so I provided both alternatives. That's the only reason.

Comment: @johnthexiii: sometimes the change should be inplace e.g., `os.walk()` allows to manipulate what directories are visited by changing `dirs` list.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for i in range(len(l)-1, 0, -1):
...    if l[i].find('(page does not exist)') > -1:
...       del (l[i])
...
>>> l
[u'File:Saddam Hussein (107).jpg']
>>>
```

Comment: `del l[i]`- you don't need the parentheses. Also `L` is a better variable name than `l`.

Comment: Note that `del` and `pop` are expensive operations for lists.(`pop` is slightly faster than `del`)