# All slice operations return a new list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, slice

In Python Tutorials, it is said "*All slice operations return a new list containing the requested elements*".

```
>>>a = ['spam', 'eggs', 100, 1234]
>>>a[0:2] = [1, 12]
>>> a
[1, 12, 100, 1234]
```

If all slice operations return a new list, how could the list **a** get changed in this example? It seems like only slice operations on the right hand return a new list.

**UPDATE**

I mean what exactly a[:] is in Python, a **reference** to a new list or a **reference** to some part of list **a** or anything else. I'm interested in the **base level** implementation not the behavior.

Comment: '=' is for assignment. And you are providing the locations in square brackets.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between `a[:]=b` and `a=b[:]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297774/what-is-the-difference-between-a-b-and-a-b)

Answer (score 4):

This is slicing:

```
b = a[0:2]
```

And this, is slice assigment:

```
a[0:2] = b
```

They're different. The latter will replace a <strike>slice</strike> part of `a` with the value of b. They look really similar, but different in use.

Answer (score 1):

'=' is for assignment. And you are providing the locations in square brackets.