# Python - appending one list to another

Tags: python, list

In my project I have a slightly more difficult peace of code but it acts exactly the way this one does:

```
seq = []
a = []

for i in range(3):
    a[:] = []
    a.append(i)
    a.append(i)

    seq.append(a)
    print seq
```

It gives as output:

```
[[0, 0]]

[[1, 1], [1, 1]]

[[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]]
```

While I want it to be:

```
[[0, 0]]

[[0, 0], [1, 1]]

[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the initialization of `a` inside the loop, currently you're appending the same list object again and again to `seq`:

```
for i in range(3):
    a = []       #or simply a = [i] * 2
    a.append(i)
    a.append(i)

    seq.append(a)
    print seq
```

If you print the id()s of items in `seq` at the end of your program you'll get the same id()s. So, all of them are references to the same list object:

```
print [id(x) for x in seq]
#[1095704328L, 1095704328L, 1095704328L]

In [106]: a = []

In [107]: seq = [a, a, a]

In [108]: a.append(1)

In [109]: seq
Out[109]: [[1], [1], [1]]

In [110]: a.append(2)

In [111]: seq
Out[111]: [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for reply now it works perfect. One last question, isnt this part: a[:] = [] making my list empty? I was sure that inside the loop I'm clearing the list, adding some data to it and then appending it to the main list.

Comment: @Desprit You're surely emptying it, but it still points to the same object. What you need to do is to create a new list object. Also read my other answer here: [What is the difference between `a[:]=b` and `a=b[:]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297774/what-is-the-difference-between-a-b-and-a-b/11297805#11297805)

Comment: @Desprit Another thing that you could do is to append a shallow copy of `a`: `seq.append(a[:])`, but it's better to create a new list object here.

Comment: Thanks sir for the link and explanation of how all this works!
Have to read once again about links cause... that was a stupid mistake)

Comment: Oh, I tried to +1 it but I couldnt because of reputation ^^ Thought the same is gonna be with Accepting.

Comment: @Desprit No reputation is required for accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
seq = []
a = []

for i in range(3):
    a = []
    a.append(i)
    a.append(i)

    seq.append(a)
    print seq
```

This runs as:

```
>>> a = []
>>> seq = []
>>> for i in range(3):
...     a = []
...     a.append(i)
...     a.append(i)
...     seq.append(a)
...     print seq
... 
[[0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [1, 1]]
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
>>>
```

Your problem was that even though you were appending different values, after you changed `a`, the values in `seq` would change too.

Comment: Accepted but cant +1, need reputation for it sorry!

Comment: No problem, now you **do** have enough reputation, :)