# What is the difference between these two ways to clear lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have seen a lot of people use either `list[:] = []` or `list = []` to make the list empty. However, what is the difference between the two?

**`list[:] = []`:**

```
>>> array = []
>>> array.append(9)
>>> array.append(4)
>>> array
[9, 4]
>>> array[:] = []
>>> array
[]
```

**`list = []`:**

```
>>> array = []
>>> array.append(9)
>>> array.append(4)
>>> array
[9, 4]
>>> array = []
>>> array
[]
>>>
```

Comment: Note that you really want `del foo[:]` or `foo.clear()` instead of the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list[:] = []` means replace all values of list with the items from the iterable on RHS(none in this case), and it affects all the references of that list object. On the other hand `list = []` is simply a new assignment.

```
In [114]: a = b = [1, 2, 3]

In [115]: c = d = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [116]: a[:] = []  

In [117]: a, b         #affects all references
Out[117]: ([], [])

In [118]: c = ['foo'] #decrements one reference count from the list pointed by `d`  

In [119]: c, d        #d is unaffected
Out[119]: (['foo'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Related: [What is the difference between `a[:]=b` and `a=b[:]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297774/what-is-the-difference-between-a-b-and-a-b)

Comment: As you can see, this was referring to the previous post you answered with me :) +1

Answer (score 2):

I think doing `list=[]` will create a new empty list, and `list[:]=[]` is still working on the same list.

```
>>> array=[]
>>> id(array)
32758680
>>> array[:]=[]
>>> id(array)
32758680
>>> array=[]
>>> id(array)
32758360
>>>
```